# How to calculate integral submanifold of this distribution?

Tags: geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm studying distributions in sense of manifolds. First of all, I didn't study differential forms.

I'm trying to understand how to calculate integral submanifolds of involutive distributions.

So, given the vector fields

$$X=x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \quad \text { and } \quad Y=\frac{\partial}{\partial z},$$

let $D$ the distribution generated by $X$ and $Y$.

I proved that the lie bracket $[X,Y]=0.$ Then $D$ is involutive and by Frobenius theorem we have $D$ integrable.

I'm trying to calculate the integrable submanifolds of $D$.

Let $p=(x,y,z).$
The integral curves of these vectors field with initial condition $p$ are:

For $X$:

$$\gamma(t)=(-y\sin(t)+x\cos(t), y\cos(t)+x\sin(t),z)$$

and for $Y$:

$$\lambda(t)=(x,y,z+t).$$

Now I'm trying to proceed in similar way of John Lee's book. (Proposition $19.28$ or Example $19.14$)

Let $$\eta(t,s,w)=\psi_{t}^{X}\circ \psi_{s}^{Y}(0,0,w)=(0,0,w+s),$$
where $\psi_{t}^{X}$ and $\psi_{s}^{Y}$ are the flow of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

In this case, the flat chat should be the inverse of $\eta.$ But, $\eta$ is not inversible.

I did some examples when we have vector fields:

$$X=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}+\alpha(x,y,z)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \text{ and } Y= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}+\beta(x,y,z)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$$

and $\alpha,\beta$ are smooth real-valued functions defined in some open set of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ satisfying

$$\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}+\beta \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}+\alpha \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial z}.$$

The method that I described above work well.

What is my error here? Have some problem is point $(0,0,0)$?

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: The curve $\gamma(t)=(-y\sin(t)+x\cos(t), y\cos(t)+x\sin(t),z)$ does not look like an integral curve of $X=x\partial_y-y\partial_x$ to me. I'd rather take a constant $r$ and (using cylindrical coordinates)
\begin{align}
\gamma(t)&=(r\cos t, r\sin t,z)=(x(t),y(t),z)\,,\\
\dot\gamma(t)&=(-r\sin t, r\cos t,0)=(-y(t),x(t),0)\,.
\end{align}

Comment: @KurtG. I wrote $X=(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3})=(-y,x,0)$ then $\gamma^{\prime}(t)=X(\gamma(t))$ give us the solution above.

In your example, I guess that I don't understand, because for $t=0$ we have $\gamma(0)=(r,0,z)$ thus $\gamma(0)$ can't pass on arbitrary point.

Comment: You are right and your $\gamma$ looks fine. I do not know Lee's book. Naively: should there not be a $t$ in $(0,0,w+s)\,?$

Answer (score 1):

Just for further reference I offer a solution using a bit of differential forms.

A one-form that annihilates both vector fields is
$$
\boldsymbol{\omega}=x\,dx+y\,dy\,.
$$
From $d\boldsymbol{\omega}=0$ it follows that  Frobenius' condition
$d\boldsymbol{\omega}\wedge\boldsymbol{\omega}=0$ holds and that
$\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is exact:
$$
\boldsymbol{\omega}=df=d\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\,.
$$
The integral manifolds are then the level sets of the function $f\,.$
In $\mathbb R^3$ each such level set is the boundary of a cylinder whose axis of symmetry is the $z$-axis.
The field $\partial_z$ is obviously tangent to that boundary.
The normal vector of the boundary is the gradient of $f\,:$
$$
\boldsymbol{n}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is obviously orthogonal to the other vector field $X\,.$ Hence, $X$
is also tangent.

Comment: Thank you, sir @Kurt G. Maybe someday I'll understand your solution. But today, I need to see my error!